# Angular 2 - Binding Component to multiple values

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel

I'm trying to implement a date range selector in Angular 2.

I already have a working widget, which I have to link to the `@angular/forms` subsystem.

What I would like is to be able to bind the two output values (let's say `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd`) to two distinct properties in the containing form's state.

Is there a way I can configure the NgModel settings to accomplish this?

An alternative could be to bind a single property of type DateRange:

```
type DateRange = {
    from: Date,
    to: Date
};
```

buyt I don't know if this is even possible.

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

What I have is a jQuery-derived, JS component which exposes an onChange, like so:

```
component.on('change', (eventData) => {
  // here I have eventData.from and eventData.to as Date values
});
```

I want to integrate this kind of handler in a Angular friendly component.
But, I can't simply do this:

```
<my-date-range-picker name"xyz" [(NgModel)]="aDateRangeValue"></my-date-range-picker>
```

Because, AFAICT, change detection is not going to work with composite values.
What should I expose in my component? Two `EventEmitter`s? Can I leverage `NgModel` in some way?

Comment: Can you provide us with some code or better explanation because I'm not sure what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: I tried to better describe my scenario. Basically I have two values, and I want to expose both as output via NgModel, or something alternative

Comment: Does my answer help with your issue ? You can make them both EventEmitters yes or even Subjects (from rxjs) depending on your needs.

Comment: Post a plunker of what you've got so far. I'll be easier to work on then...

Comment: @JGFMK I have other 5 controls binding to simple values, exposing values to the forms module, through ControlValueAccessor interface. ControlValueAccessor gives a lot of benefits, but seems limited to exposing  single value. Now I'm wondering how could I do the same (implementing a ControlValueAccessor) with 2 values (or, in other words, a single value defined by two dates).

Comment: @JGFMK in other words, I don't have a working "something" to post.

Comment: @A.Chiesa 'I already have a working widget' <(^- ')>

Comment: Sorry, JGFMK, it's better rephrased as "I already have a working __jQuery__ widget". Nothing Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, you *can* have models of any kind.

So, I used the base classes from [this article](http://blog.rangle.io/angular-2-ngmodel-and-custom-form-components/), here is the most relevant:

```
export class ValueAccessorBase<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {  
  private innerValue: T;


  private changed = new Array<(value: T) => void>();
  private touched = new Array<() => void>();


  get value(): T {
    return this.innerValue;
  }


  set value(value: T) {
    if (this.innerValue !== value) {
      this.innerValue = value;
      this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
    }
  }


  touch() {
    this.touched.forEach(f => f());
  }


  writeValue(value: T) {
    this.innerValue = value;
  }


  registerOnChange(fn: (value: T) => void) {
    this.changed.push(fn);
  }


  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.touched.push(fn);
  }
}
```

This happens to work even when `T` is a class, with `from` and `to` properties, in my case:

```
@Component(
  ...
)
class DateRangeComponent extends ValueAccessorBase<DateRange> {
  ... implementation

  // somewhere after the view init:
  jqueryComponent.on('change', (eventData) => {
   // here I have eventData.from and eventData.to as Date values
   this.value = {
     from: eventData.from,
     to: eventData.to
   };
  });
}
```

So, if everyone else stumbles upon this question, the answer is: go ahead and write your own component.

As a side note, this works best when using forms only to prepare Json objects to be sent in Ajax calls. An old fashioned form-encoded submit would be less linear.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create you own `ngModel` like two-way data-binding, that's what you should do:

```
@Component()
export class MyComponent {

      myValue = 0;

      @Output()
      myValueChange = new EventEmitter();

      @Input()
      get myValue() {
             return this.myValue;
      }

      set myValue(val) {
           this.myValue= val;
           this.myValueChange.emit(this.myValue);
      }
}
```

Now you can use it as follows and have two-way data binding in effect:

```
<my-component [(myValue)]="someExpression"></my-component>
```

Adding a link to a simple tutorial on this as well: http://www.angulartraining.com/blog/tutorial-create-your-own-two-way-data-binding-in-angular/

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `Output` directives.

`<my-date-range-picker name"xyz" [dateTo]="dateTo" [dateFrom]="dateFrom"></my-date-range-picker>`

While in your component you would have

```
import { Output } from '@angular/core';
.
.
@Output() dateTo: any; // EventEmitter, Subject, Number, String, doesn't matter ...
@Output() dateFrom: any;
```

Here's a reference to component interaction using `Input` and `Output`

[Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction])

Comment: Yes, but could I attach validation and form binding to simple Output directives? I'm trying to understand what limits are there in the possible approaches.

Comment: If you use them as EventEmitters or Subjects you can subscribe to them and use validation on those events